# How to enable/disable Google's reCaptcha widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha, disabled-input

Is there a way to programmatically enable/disable Google's reCaptcha widget? The purpose for this would be to prevent a user from clicking the *"I'm not a robot"* checkbox prematurely.

Comment: Can you not just hide the element?

Comment: Of course that's possible, but that would be an approach I'd take if some kind of disable/enable functionality does not exist that I'm unaware of. I looked through Google's documentation and didn't see anything, so I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a solution.

Comment: I would think you could delay the .render method based on the callback completing from some event, like the last element of your form being populated or whatever you choose.

Comment: Ah gotcha. This might be possible with [custom theming](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization#Custom_Theming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21324696/1454671).

Add this CSS:

```
.disabled-element {
    opacity: 0.65;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Add the `disabled-element` class to the `div` containing the reCaptcha element:

```
<script>
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    alert("grecaptcha is ready!");
  };
</script>

<div class="disabled-element" id="captcha"></div>
...
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

And finally, whenever you're ready to enable the reCaptcha element, remove the class:

```
$("#captcha").removeClass("disabled-element");
```